# How to configure Bind9 as forwarder only?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I need to configure a DNS forwarder server and so far I've stumped over [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-caching-or-forwarding-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) tutorial. See the config below. My issue is that I don't want to block clients(i.e. `goodclients`) from accessing the server because I'm planning to publish it in the domain name NS records.
  The question is how can I configure it for forwarding only (no querying) in a secure manner ? Basically I want to use the forwarder as a "vanity" server without the risks of DDOS mentioned in the article.

```
acl goodclients {
        107.170.41.189;
        localhost;
        localnets;
};

options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        recursion yes;
        allow-query { goodclients; };

        forwarders {
                8.8.8.8;
                8.8.4.4;
        };
        forward only;

        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, that you simply want to allow queries from all clients but only allow recursion/forwarding for select networks, it would appear that you probably didn't actually want to set [`allow-query`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) in the first place but rather set [`allow-recursion`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) instead.

It's well worth reading the official manual (linked above) regarding the `allow-*` settings, in particular the defaults and how these settings interact.